# gcloud container images delete issue

Tags: containers, gcloud

I am having trouble using the `gcloud container images delete` command. When trying to delete an image listed by the `gcloud container images list` command it is said to not be found. Must I use the `delete` command with other parameters to successfully delete?

```
$ gcloud container images list
NAME
gcr.io/stemnapp/alpine-nodejs

$ gcloud container images delete gcr.io/stemnapp/alpine-nodejs
ERROR: (gcloud.container.images.delete) [gcr.io/stemnapp/alpine-nodejs:latest] is not a valid name.
```

Comment: What tags does that image have?

Comment: `gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/stemnapp/alpine-nodejs` returns c64e7ec2fbaf, a6ea86e1c46a, and 5ab3878d24b5.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [documentation for `gcloud container images delete`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/delete):

> **POSITIONAL ARGUMENTS**
>
> `IMAGE_NAME [IMAGE_NAME …]`
>
> The fully qualified name(s) of image(s) to delete. The name(s) should be  formatted as `*.gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE_PATH@sha256:DIGEST` or `*.gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE_PATH:TAG`.

Because deleting is a dangerous operation, gcloud requires you to be very specific. You should provide the tag of the image that you want to delete, or the sha256 digest of the image that you want to delete.

(I'll make sure that error message gets cleaned up so it's clearer what to do.)